# converting physical windows 2003 server through disk to vhd tool to hyper-v server

Tags: hyper-v, diskmanagement

i am trying to do P2V conversion through disk to vhd tool. conversion is successful but after conversion when i attach the disk c: drive or d: drive its shows additional drives in disk management same as c: and d: drive

why additional disks are showing ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, this is actually the expected behavior from converting the disk from P2V, you get the same partitions and data within the partitions inside a VHD/VHDX file. When you attach the newly created VHD/VHDX image file into your computer, the drive letters will be different than what they were originally been using on the original disk.

From your image, assuming that Disk 0 is the base drive you're trying to convert into a virtual disk, do the following:

1. On Disk 1, the 39 GB partition, assign a drive letter and confirm that the files and folders are the same on Disk 0, partition C:, if the files are the same, then the conversion completed successfully for this drive.
2. On Disk 1, Drive D, if there is no files in there, just delete the partition.
3. Create a new VM and attached the newly created disk to it, boot it and you should have a replica of the physical machine as a VM.

I would be more worried about the Windows 2003 compatibility with Hyper-V, you need to install the integration tools: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/243b5705-96c9-4ec7-9ec5-c68a22b0d42d